# No convolution Identity element in $L^1_{per} $ using Fourier series

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series, distribution-theory, fourier-transform, convolution

We have to show that there is no identity element for the ring $ L^1_{per}( ]0,2\pi [) $ specifically using the Fourier coeffcients.

Suppose that : $ \exists e , \: \: e * f = f \: \: \: \: \forall f   $

Then $ c_n(f) = \widehat f  \widehat e (n)   $ and $ \widehat e (x) = 1 $

I know that $  \widehat 1 = 2 \pi \delta_0 $ and this is a distribution hence not in $ L^1 $ but here want don't want to use this result.

Am I allowed to talk about Fourier series for functions in $ L^1_{per}( ]0,2\pi [) $ space ?? I know that there are convergence theorems for continuous periodic functions and also $ L^2 $ functions but what can we say here?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you'll want to use the [Riemann-Lebesgue Lemma for Fourier coefficients](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann%E2%80%93Lebesgue_lemma#Other_versions).  Clearly, $\hat e(n)$ does not vanish as $|n|\to\infty$.  Note that the Fourier coefficients of $f$ are perfectly well defined for $f\in L^1$; the issue is the Fourier inversion formula, but that's not needed for the RL Lemma.